# why mainWindow.minimize() doesn't function

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to minimize the electron app screen and I have this:

This is the HTML for creating the buttons:

```
<div class="close-container">
   <div class="minimize-button"></div>
   <div class="close-button">&#10005;</div>
</div>
```

This is the code in renderer:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer; 
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');
const minimizeButton = document.querySelector('.minimize-button');

closeButton.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('close');
});

minimizeButton.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    console.log('minX');
    ipcRenderer.send('minimize');
});
```

And here is my main.js

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    // width: 1536,
    // height: 864,
    fullscreen: true,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration:  true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

  ipcMain.on('minimize', () => {
    console.log('reached here');
    mainWindow.minimize();
  });

  ipcMain.on('close', () => {
    mainWindow.close();
  });

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}
```

All the code works fine (I can see  `console log('reached here')`) except mainWindow.minimize(); which is not doing its job, Minimizing the screen.

So the .minimize() method is not functioning properly.

What I'm missing? How to fix this?

Comment: Is the problem persisting when you set `fullscreen: false`?

Comment: As you know JavaScript will never be a programming language and it has a lot of  bugs ... I solve this by using a 200 ms timeout .... and it works fine then...

Comment: Where did you add the timeout? in the `minimize` event handler or in the renderer? Seems like it could be an issue with electron.

Comment: `setTimeout(() =>mainWindow.minimize(), 200);`